# Higher-dimensional algebraic subgroups of the proalgebraic Nottingham group?

Tags: algebraic-groups, profinite-groups, gr.group-theory, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-dynamics

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and, for $n\ge0$,
${\mathcal{A}}_n={\mathcal{A}}_n(R)$ the group of series
$u(x)=\sum_0^\infty a_jx^{j+1}\in R[[x]]$ for which
$a_0\in R^\times$ and $u(x)\equiv x\pmod{x^{n+1}}$.
The group operation is composition of series.
A series in ${\mathcal{A}}_n$ that’s not in ${\mathcal{A}}_{n+1}$
is said to have depth $n$. When $\kappa$ is a field with $p^s$ elements,
${\mathcal{A}}_1(\kappa)$ is often called the Nottingham
group, but it seems to have been designated by different
names in different times and places.

One sees that ${\mathcal{A}}_n$ is the projective limit of
the groups ${\mathcal{A}}_n/{\mathcal{A}}_{n+r}$, and for $n>0$
these are unipotent algebraic groups of dimension $r$. So
it's the proalgebraic group ${\mathcal{A}}_1$, defined over
${\mathbb{F}}_p$, that I'm asking
about, and the existence of (finite-dimensional) algebraic
subgroups in it.

There's one that's obvious, namely the image of
${\mathbf{G}}_{\mathrm a}\to {\mathcal{A}}_1$ by
the homomorphism
    $$
    t\mapsto \frac{x}{1-tx}
    =x+tx^2+t^2x^3+\cdots=u_t(x)
    $$
fractional-linear transformation leaving the origin fixed,
expanded as series.

Almost as obvious is to apply the
transformation
$$
u(x)=x(1+g(x))\mapsto (u(x^m))^{1/m}
=x(1+g(x^m))^{1/m}
$$
clearly a group homomorphism, well defined when $m$ is prime
to $p$, because you're raising a principal unit to an exponent
that's in ${\mathbb{Z}}_p$. This takes $u_t$, a subgroup of
Nottingham of depth one to a group of depth $m$. In particular,
the Nottingham proalgebraic group has lots of one-dimensional
algebraic subgroups.

There are no commutative connected algebraic subgroups of
dimension greater than $1$: I've found an argument that
depends on higher
ramification theory and uses Hasse-Arf, but breaks down
completely in any noncommutative case. I would like to settle the question of whether there are any
algebraic subgroups of Nottingham of dimension greater than
$1$, necessarily noncommutative: it will be enough to dispose
of the two-dimensional case. So it occurs to me that this may
already be known, or maybe someone out there can suggest an
approach to me.

Comment: Don't you mean $a_0=0$ instead of $a_0\in R^\times$?

Comment: @Yves: No, he means $a_0\in R^{\times}$, because he's labeled his series as $a_0x+a_1x^2+a_2x^3+\cdots$. (Note that the $j$'th term in his sum is $a_jx^{j+1}$.) Although slightly nonstandard, it's a useful labeling for composition of unit power series. OTOH, for $n\ge1$, his congruence condition forces $a_0=1$ for all power series in $\mathcal{A}_n$. But $\mathcal{A}_0$ contains all series with $a_0\in R^{\times}$.

Comment: The numbering is nonstandard for me, but seems very common usage among the group theorists.

Comment: Indeed, becasue (pro-$p$) group theorists usually take $a_0=1$. So if we would have numbered the usual way, then we would have to start with $a_2$. Also many times we write the elemnts as $x(1+g(x))$, so this way $g(x)$ has the "right" form. 

Comment: Regarding your question, several years ago I talked with Steve Donkin about the Nottingham group and as I rememebr he thought about it as a proalgebraic group. So you might want to ask him.

Comment: Is there a classification of 2-dimensional connected unipotent groups (over an algebraically closed field)? If $K$ has char. zero there is only the abelian one so the question is settled if $R$ has char. zero. But it characteristic $p$ there are further examples, e.g. the subgroup of the Heisenberg group of matrices satisfying $a_{23}=a_{12}^p$.

Comment: @Yves, right. I’ve been looking at the group in char. $2$ with `$a_{23}=a_{12}^4$` as a possible occurrence, but let’s face it, my technique is not strong enough.